# Is there a way to tell WebBrowser component C# not to alter the original HTML?

Tags: c#, html, tags, browser

I have noticed that Internet Explorer, which is used by the Web Browser component, modifies the original sourcecode. I undestand that some of the code must change due ajax requests and everything. When I stated that the html is modified, I refer to those tags that are inserted even when they are not in the actual sourcecode. For example, IE completes the "body" tag when is not present, also the "tbody" tag when a table does not have it. Is there a way to keep the original structure of the document?

If you dont understand the question let me know, thanks.

Comment: I am letting you know that I don't understand the question.

Comment: Do you need to use WebBrowser component? Is it possible for your needs to use WebClient to make an http request? I think this way the response wouldn't be modified.

Comment: If you need the original serever Response, you can use HttpWebRequest to query the server, and get the original, umodified, HttpWebResponse.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov, basically the WebBrowser modifies the html DOM when it is loaded. David Diaz and JotaBe, I have to use the WebBrowser, because I also have to process AJAX, and some other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make some assumptions but here is my theory:

What you are seeing is not IE altering the HTML. I don't know how you saw this but this is IE serializing its DOM tree. Of course IE must close the body tag (or create the body DOM element if we have to be exact) in order to render something. The serialized DOM is not what the original HTML was and if you want to extract the original HTML you are probably not using the right tool. This behaviour sometimes surfaces in WSIYWYG editors and when using save page in IE. It just dumps its internal DOM tree back into a string and in a DOM tree there are no incomplete elements because they are tree nodes not tags.

Comment: +1: Yeah, I would say he's looking at the DOM, too, based on what he is posting.

Comment: Yes I am looking at the DOM, because that's what I need to do. So the answer is there's no way to tell Explorer to add the extra nodes when it is serializing the document?

Comment: Those nodes are in the IE DOM. This is how IE sees the HTML you provided. It did not add the elements it just sees them implicitly. I doubt there is a way to tell it that but then again I am not an expert.

Comment: Maybe you can use the HTML agility pack to work with the HTML instead of the IE DOM?

Comment: I need to do it with the explorer.

Comment: Well, good luck but I don't think IE has the ability to build DOM without those elements.